# StoreFront Wordpress theme: How can i create a new Home page with Custom design same as template

Tags: php, wordpress, storefront

I am getting too frustrated while creating new home page using template in Storefront theme. https://wordpress.org/themes/storefront/.

With the help of this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/
i tried bt not getting success.. anyone can tell me how can i do this without plug-in..
I want to change home page , and want to show my custom template home page. –

**Updated:**

I did not tried Child theme. But i think i have find out the issue.. My template name is not listing in Word press admin menu .. I tried with Twenty twelve bt same issue , template name not is in List during add page. –

**Template Script**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: Homepage My Custom
 *
 * @package storefront
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            **My Custom Home Template**
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What you want to do? want to change design of home page? or any other things?

Comment: yes i want to change home page , and want to show my custom template home page.

Comment: ok so you created custom page? can you show that code?

Comment: ok now what issue you are facing? does this custom template not reflecting on home page?

Comment: StoreFront showing me only two template in Wp-admin 1. Homepage and 2. Full width. but not showing my "Homepage My Custom". Thats why i am able to activate custom template as Home page template.

Comment: In admin , Do you not getting? your custom page template name in pages->Home->Select Template ?